# Conditional strings in String.format() in Java

Tags: java

I have a program to convert a given number of minutes in days/hours/minutes and so on.

I am trying to not display the part `x days` if days = 0. Similarly for hrs, and mins.

So some sample outputs would be:

```
5 days
```

--

```
5 days 2 hrs
```

--

```
2 hrs 10 mins
```

etc.

How can I do it without convoluting my print statement with a bunch of ternary operators?

My current solution is :

```
        final StringBuilder remDaysBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        long remMins = Math.abs(request.getTimeRemaining());

        final int remDays = (int) (remMins / 1440);
        if (remDays > 0) {
            remDaysBuilder.append(remDays + " Days");
        }
        remMins = remMins % 1440;
        final int remHrs = (int) (remMins / 60);
        if (remHrs > 0) {
            remDaysBuilder.append(remHrs + " Hrs");
        }
        remMins = remMins % 60;
        if (remMins > 0) {
            remDaysBuilder.append(remMins + " Mins");
        }
```

But I feel this is too much code for such a small logic!

Comment: [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)

Comment: This is  normal amount of code for this logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Elliott, I went with `java.time.Duration` package, which reduced a lot of complexity, but obviously doesn't do anything for the `println` statements.

After some searching on SO, I've come across [DurationFormatUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html) which serves my purpose perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
final StringBuilder remDaysBuilder = new StringBuilder();

long remMins = Math.abs(request.getTimeRemaining());

final int remDays = remMins/24/60;
final int remHours = remMins/60%24;
final int remMins = remMins % 60;

remDaysBuilder
    .append(String.format("%s",(remDays>0)?(Integer.toString(remDays)+" days "):"")
    .append(String.format("%s",(remHours>0)?(Integer.toString(remHours)+" days "):"")
    .append(String.format("%s",(remMins>0)?(Integer.toString(remMins)+" days "):"");
```

This way it becomes more readable as well as its short.

Comment: This is a cosmetic improvement. I went with `java.time.Duration` as suggested by @Elliott Frisch

Answer (score 0):

Reduce repetition by writing auxiliary subroutines.

First...

```
  private static long addTerm(StringBuilder sb, long rem, int div, String what) {
       int n = (int)(rem / div);
       if (n > 0) sb.append(n)
                    .append(' ')
                    .append(what)
                    .append(n > 1 ? "s " : " ");
       return rem % div;
    }
```

and then...

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    long remMins = Math.abs(request.getTimeRemaining());
    remMins = addTerm(sb, remMins, 1440, "Day");
    remMins = addTerm(sb, remMins, 60, "Hr");
    remMins = addTerm(sb, remMins, 1, "Min");
```

(This code is not thoroughly checked but it should be sufficient to convey the idea)